# Reduce ranges of doubles in C++

Tags: c++

I've seen various approaches in other languages for how to do this, but it seems like a common enough problem that it seems like there should be a standard way to do this.

I want to collapse a list of float ranges to its smallest representation.

2.45-3.72
3.16-6.55
7.23-8.96
8.95-10.27

would become:

2.45-6.55
7.23-10.27

Is there a function or library in C++ somewhere that I can give my list to, and it will perform the reduction for me?  I could easily write my own, but why bother if it already exists?

Comment: That doesn't seem like a very common problem(I've never encountered it at least), and it's definitely not something you would expect to find in the standard library(though it may be in a third party library, I don't know)

Comment: it doesn't exist, but since it's easy to write your own, why bother asking?

Comment: The code to actually solve this problem would be interesting to write, though it's not really that hard.  Sounds like a good interview question.

Comment: If you look into any algorithms book that has trees and geometry you will see descriptions of how to efficiently implement your requirements. I can recommend you [Introduction to algorithms](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Third-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262033844).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound simple:

- start with list of ranges
- let **current** = first range in the list
- while there's a **next** range after **current**:

  - if **next** overlaps **current**:

    - extend **current** to also contain **next**
    - remove **next** from the list
  - else:

    - advance **current** one forward

That should do the trick.

Comment: This assumes that the ranges are sorted, which wasn't stated in the question (but yes, it does work for the one example given)

Answer (score 2):

Boost has an [interval library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm).  This doesn't explicitly contain exactly what you need, but might make it easier to write it.

Personally, looking at the documentation, it worries me that the library does not attempt to let you clearly distinguish between closed and open intervals.  But this may not be important for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be any solution provided by the Standard, it's way too specific.

Comment: What about Boost? Or some other library...?

Comment: @NielW: If you know about Boost, check it yourself. It's not my job to check sources of information you already know about.

Comment: @DeadMG Boost is big and intimidating, and can be difficult to find the functions you're looking for.  Maybe somebody familiar with the problem can point him directly to it.  You may as well have said, "If you know about Google, check it yourself".  It's not any of our jobs to answer ANY questions on here.

Comment: @PigBen: Boost is not big or intimidating, and it's documentation is clearly written. Checking Boost is not the same as checking Google. Boost has standards- anyone can throw up any crap on Google, and many orders of magnitude smaller. It's not unreasonable to ask someone to check Boost first unless they specify that they can't use it.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that if @DeadMG had known of a Boost library to do this, he would have mentioned it. The context of his comment is important. It is not "I don't intend to help you find out", but rather "I don't know, and there's no point in me looking it up for you when you might as well look it up yourself".

Comment: @jalf: You're right - I didn't mean to sound like, "Go help yourself", but more like, "I'm not going to be any more effective searching Boost than you are.". I re-read my comment and it could seem a bit off.